# Changing tick marks on geom_mosaic plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, mosaic-plot, ggmosaic

I have the following dataset in R, which I want to make into a mosaic plot using ggplot2 and ggmosaic.

```
type   variable count residuals residcut residround
see.m       aca    44  4.380270     high          4
see.nm      aca    26 -3.063712      low         -3
see.m      conv    48 -1.562652      low         -2
see.nm     conv   135  1.092973   medium          1
see.m       fic    27 -2.194561      low         -2
see.nm      fic    98  1.534951   medium          2
see.m      news    17  1.504522   medium          2
see.nm     news    19 -1.052315      low         -1
```

I am using the following code, which gives me the plot below :

```
ggplot(see.reg2) + geom_mosaic(aes(x = product(type, variable), weight = count, fill = type))
```

[image]

I am wondering if there is a possible way to change the way the tick marks on the bottom are done, so that I only see four ticks: one for each level of 'variable', rather than seeing eight tick marks (one for each interaction).

Thank you!

Comment: The fill argument shown in the plot is type, not residcut. Running the code you posted but using type, as you've shown, gets me a plot with labels such as "aca", "conv", etc., not the ones you got. I'm on a development version of `ggmosaic`, 0.1.2.9000

Comment: Sorry camille! I meant to type in 'type' in the example code. I changed it in my question. Though I will add, when I include the fill = residcut, I also get interaction-type x axis tick marks, instead of the four I want.

Comment: What version are you using? Because I don't get interaction tick marks

Comment: I am using version 0.1.2.

Comment: Try updating to the version on Github, because I'm not having the same problem with it